# Unison replacing newer symlinks with older files using the option -force newer

Tags: symlink, synchronization, unison

I'm having a problem with Unison and symlinks. I created a test case for making it easier to understand and try this for yourself.

First, we create the two directories that will be synced. And some files in the first directory.

```
~/testdir$ mkdir a
~/testdir$ mkdir b
~/testdir$ echo "hello" > a/one
~/testdir$ echo "goodbye" > a/two
```

We run unison with these parameters. It should preserve modification times and force the updates to newer files.

```
~/testdir$ unison -force newer -times -auto -batch a b
```

After running this, I have an exact duplicate.

```
a:
total 16K
drwx------ 2 pruebas.ubuntu citius 4,0K oct  8 16:51 .
drwx------ 4 pruebas.ubuntu citius 4,0K oct  8 16:50 ..
-rw------- 1 pruebas.ubuntu citius    6 oct  8 16:52 one
-rw------- 1 pruebas.ubuntu citius    8 oct  8 16:52 two

b:
total 16K
drwx------ 2 pruebas.ubuntu citius 4,0K oct  8 16:52 .
drwx------ 4 pruebas.ubuntu citius 4,0K oct  8 16:50 ..
-rw------- 1 pruebas.ubuntu citius    6 oct  8 16:52 one
-rw------- 1 pruebas.ubuntu citius    8 oct  8 16:52 two
```

Here comes the problem. I delete one of those files and replace it with a symbolic link.

```
~/testdir/a$ rm one
~/testdir/a$ ln -s two one
~/testdir/a$ ls -lah
total 12K
drwx------ 2 pruebas.ubuntu citius 4,0K oct  8 16:55 .
drwx------ 4 pruebas.ubuntu citius 4,0K oct  8 16:54 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 pruebas.ubuntu citius    3 oct  8 16:55 one -> two
-rw------- 1 pruebas.ubuntu citius    8 oct  8 16:54 two
```

Then, Unison deletes the symbolic link and replaces it with the older version of the file.

```
~/testdir$ unison -force newer -times -auto -batch a b
Contacting server...
Looking for changes
Reconciling changes
new link <====            one  
Propagating updates
UNISON 2.40.102 started propagating changes at 16:56:25.03 on 08 Oct 2014
[BGN] Copying one from /home/remoto/pruebas.ubuntu/testdir/b to /home/remoto/pruebas.ubuntu/testdir/a
[END] Copying one
UNISON 2.40.102 finished propagating changes at 16:56:25.03 on 08 Oct 2014
Saving synchronizer state
Synchronization complete at 16:56:25  (1 item transferred, 0 skipped, 0 failed)
~/testdir$ ls -lah a
total 16K
drwx------ 2 pruebas.ubuntu citius 4,0K oct  8 16:56 .
drwx------ 4 pruebas.ubuntu citius 4,0K oct  8 16:54 ..
-rw------- 1 pruebas.ubuntu citius    6 oct  8 16:54 one
-rw------- 1 pruebas.ubuntu citius    8 oct  8 16:54 two
```

This won't happen if I don't use the option `-force newer`. This seems like a strange behaviour to me, though. The [manual](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html) says:

> You can also specify -force newer (or -force older) to force Unison
>   to choose the file with the later (earlier) modtime. In this case, the
>   -times preference must also be enabled.

It seems like Unison is not following this behaviour with symlinks. Does this seem like a bug to you? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I have observe the same bogue on unison 2.40.61 The only workarround I have found is to not use the force option.
I have tested 2.48.3, same problem